# Show next series of data when scope value change in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I tried like below

```
startIndex = 0;
lengthIndex = 5;

<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" ng-click="startIndex = startIndex-1"></span>
  <ul>
<li ng-repeat="week in mydata | limitTo:lengthIndex:startIndex">
 </ul>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" ng-click="startIndex = startIndex-1"></span>
```

When scope value changes i want the next set of data to be shown. But when page is refreshed, it shows the data properly i.e. slices of data. But on click scope value is changing but data does not change. How do i fix this.

Comment: Were you able to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope So when you try to access `startIndex` it will access the child scope and update the value in the child scope only.To change the value in the parent scope of the `ng-repeat` either use `$parent.startIndex` as given below

```
<li ng-repeat="week in mydata | limitTo:lengthIndex:startIndex">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" ng-click="$parent.startIndex = $parent.startIndex-1"></span>
```

or make `startIndex` an object which will ensure the parent property is accessed and updated.

```
<li ng-repeat="week in mydata | limitTo:lengthIndex:index.startIndex">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" ng-click="index.startIndex = index.startIndex-1"></span>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H3pw0a3xCrkHN2yFBXJm?p=preview) is a working example as per your updated code

Comment: Please see the code now. I have updated it. I think i pasted code wrongly.

Comment: @Hacker Can you create an example in plunker/jsfiddle please?

Comment: @Hacker Here is a working example http://plnkr.co/edit/H3pw0a3xCrkHN2yFBXJm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

when you are using ng-repeat, angular digest process continue till the end of the loop.
so it will break the link to the index from the scope and will reflect after refresh because it provide new scope at that time.

This is just a traditional async function with a $scope.$apply() called at the end, to tell AngularJS that an asynchronous event just occurred.

so when ever you are changes scope variable which is in ng-repeat must use $scope.$apply().